# Advanced Binary Exploitation CTF

Tags: binary-analysis, binary, exploit, binary-diagnosis

I wanted to ask your assistance: Where can I find advanced ctfs (that hopefully contain solutions) regarding binary/kernel exploitation? I am interested on finding x86_64 linux/windows/arm64 that consist of userland or kernel(lkm or drivers) exploitation (overcoming modern mitigations such as "shadow stacks" or different control flow guards(cfg/acg/others..) and grooming tricks and similar are huge pluses).
What I am mostly looking for is ctfs that imitate mundane situations or applications, including but not limited to: common errors, uaf (even double free), bad custom memory layouts(for instance custom mmap implementations), different leaks, finding primitives, disclosures and similar -- all of it either in userland or appropriate kernel level.

Sadly I could not find anything that consists of what I call "modern world", with modern mitigations that is not aimed at basic corrupting the stack/heap, basic usage of tools or concepts, or anything that basically teaches the basics (corrupting/polluting, got/plt overwrites, simple ropper and similar basics - but something that goes beyond that, that can teach "real skills"). I am looking to expand my knowledge and I am pretty sure your answers would help a lot of people that are wondering about the same too, and couldn't find what they were looking for.

Note: I mentioned solutions because the amount of knowledge and tricks that can be taught just by reading a write up is huge, especially way of thinking, grooming, way of reversing and approaching the situation and similar. I learn a lot from reading write ups but I couldn't find ones that are above the "beginner" level.

I am looking to expand my knowledge and I am pretty sure your answers would help a lot of people that are wondering about the same too, and couldn't find what they were looking for.

Just to be clear again: I am not referring to dep/aslr/canaries and similar(those were awesome a decade ago). What I am looking for is the step after that.

Doesn't have to be binary, can be firmware, lkm, drivers, handles/pipes and similar.

Thank you very much and have a great week.

Comment: Not sure this question format is suitable for the site or even has an actual answer. Just look at real life software, it will be more useful than any CTF.

Comment: For Windows Exploitation, take a look at the Corelan's tutorials. I'm thinking of this one in particular, for a good introduction to the 'modern' Windows exploits protections: https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2009/09/21/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-6-bypassing-stack-cookies-safeseh-hw-dep-and-aslr/

Answer (score 1):

## For Modern Binary Exploitation

https://github.com/nnamon/linux-exploitation-course 
https://exploit.education/fusion/

## For Kernel Exploitation

https://github.com/xairy/linux-kernel-exploitation 
https://github.com/s0wr0b1ndef/linux-kernel-exploitation